# Open help on current word

Tags: vim, neovim

Example:
Open the vim configuration and move the cursor to `shortmess`.
Now i would like to open any available help context to the current word.

I could write a function to run that command:

```
:h shortmess
```

Is there already a built-in feature to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try the following mapping:

`nnoremap <your-mapping> :h <c-r><c-w><cr>`

it takes the current word under your cursor and searches the help pages.
see `:h c_CTRL-R`

In order to use K you have to `set keywordprg=:help`, since the default value is man. see `:h K`

Answer (score 4):

I think you can press `K` in normal mode to achieve this